# Remote Desktop will not connect using hostname, DNS issue related to WLAN/LAN switching

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, remote-desktop

We have a set of wireless devices in our directory. While these are connected wirelessly, I can connect Remote Desktop with no problems. The issue is when it's connected directly, the hostname seems to still direct to the wireless IP.

Doing an nslookup on the hostname shows that both IPs are registered, and if I connect using the wired IP address, there are no issues. I've also found that finding the target PC in the Active Directory tools and using the "Manage" tool will connect to it regardless of what connection it is currently using.

Through my troubleshooting, it basically seems like I'm not receiving the current address from the DNS server. What would be causing this?
I've searched google and here, but I can't find anyone else with this issue, or I'm not searching with the right terms.

Comment: Are you using DHCP for the clients in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A windows machine will register both IPs in the DNS, so i normal situation the DNS contains 2 entry for the machine and you client computer will randomly get one from the server (in a round-robin way)

Eventually the aging / scavenging process will remove one of the entry but usually this will be after several days.. so there's chance the computer will connect with both address and refresh the records before the scavenging, so in fact you will always have both records presents.

On top of that you have the caches, on both server and client

Note that a nslookup may provide different result from what the programs actually get, because nslookup doesn't use the local dns client cache, but query directly the DNS server.

So in you're case there's no simple solution, apart maybe a small script that will flush the dns client cache before each try...